# Python's StringIO for Clojure

Tags: python, clojure, stringio

Is there something equivalent to Python's [StingIO](http://docs.python.org/library/stringio.html) for Clojure?

I'm trying to write a report generating/literate programming system similar to [Sweave](http://www.stat.uni-muenchen.de/~leisch/Sweave/) and [Pweave](http://mpastell.com/pweave/) for Clojure. I'm currently using a temp file, but I'd prefer using something similar to StringIO.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**with-out-str** is pretty handy.

```
(let [foo (with-out-str (println "Hello world!"))] 
   foo)
```

More documentation [here](http://clojuredocs.org/v/1652)

Comment: having some references embedded in this answer would be nice.

Comment: Thanks, thats exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 2):

java.io.StringWriter: http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/StringWriter.html